# Local variable 'body' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, twitter

There have been such questions before, but I can't find my solution in any of them.

I am making a simple Python app to stream the public Twitter streams. This is my code

```
from twitter import *

APP_KEY = 'XXX'
APP_SECRET = 'XXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN = 'XXX'
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'XXX'
auth = OAuth(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
twitter_stream = TwitterStream(auth)
iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.sample()
for tweet in iterator:
    print tweet
```

And the error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch.py", line 9, in <module>
    iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.sample()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter-1.10.2-py2.7.egg/twitter/api.py", line 207, in __call__
    req = urllib_request.Request(uriBase, body, headers)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'body' referenced before assignment
```

So, the error is actually in a function in the twitter module, as the message says, which is not probable, and I must be making some error. The documentation for the twitter module, if needed, can be found at https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the class definition for `TwitterStream` it appear that you need to pass in the `auth` variable as a **keyword argument** like `TwiterStream(auth=auth)` in your case or `TwitterStream(auth=my_auth_variable)` in the general case.

The first argument of the `TwitterStream` `__init__` function appears to be `domain`, and so you've passed in your auth object as the domain which is of course causing problems.

If you are really keen, you could suggest to the project author that he checks this kind of thing more rigorously in his code so that he can present useful error messages to users of his library!

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks, and yes, the error messages in this library are not useful at all..

Comment: SO is the extended Twitter Api Documentation.